# Tips for golfing in TikZ

Tags: code-golf, tips

[TikZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) is a Latex package used for drawing precise images in Latex documents.  It has a massive specification and a boatload of features that may be useful for [graphical-output](/questions/tagged/graphical-output) style questions.

What tips do people have for golfing in TikZ?  As always, tips should be specific to to TikZ (e.g. "Remove comments" is not an answer), and stick to a single tip per answer.

Comment: Does anyone golf in Tikz?

Comment: @Pavel [I do.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109433/56656)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question for meta ?

Comment: @WheatWizard  It seems like a question about "how to approach answering a question" , rather than a programming puzzle itself. I see there's a tips tag, so I assume it's on-topic on the main site. Still learning the ropes on this site, so questions about how to approach answering/reducing answers seems  more suitable for meta site rather than main one.

Comment: @Serg There are a good deal of [tag:tips] questions of similar content on the main site.  These are generally considered to be on-topic.

Comment: For those interested, there is a tikz/pgf manual (its where I found the information for my answers).

[Version 3.0.1a](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf),
[Version 2.10](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)

Comment: Do you think this question is worth generalizing/editing to "Tips for golfing in TeX/LaTeX", or should I create a new question? Things like `\def` are not specific to TikZ, and I have some more answers I'd like to add (but none are TikZ-related).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think perhaps a new question should be made for TeX/LaTeX, all of the tips here are currently specific to Tikz, and I can see some benefit in keeping them separate.

Comment: @WheatWizard Ok makes sense; I've created a new question [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123901/3845).

Answer (score 5):

## Use `\def`

`\def` is an incredibly powerful tool when it comes to golfing.  `\def` allows you to assign something to a variable.

This can be used simply with the to save a number you may use a bunch of times for instance

```
\def\x{1456}
```

Will define `1456` as `\x` for future use much like saving a variable might in a programming language.

However `\def` is much more powerful than that, because `\def` doesn't define a variable it defines a snippet of code to be substituted into the program whenever it is called.

For example say you want to draw some rectangles using `\draw`  you might write the following code:

```
\draw(0,0)rectangle(3,4)rectangle(8,0);\draw(2,2)rectangle(3,3);
```

Using `\def` this could be written as:

```
\def\x{)rectangle(}\draw(0,0\x3,4\x8,0);\draw(2,2\x3,3);
```

Comment: This is brilliant in golfing point of view but also very useful to more deeply understand these important commands...you know when they ask you "what is the difference between \def and \newcommand"...

Answer (score 4):

## Use `\tikz` instead of the `tikzpicture` environment

Instead of creating a `tikzpicture` environment (36 bytes) you can use the `\tikz` command (7 bytes)

Global options can be set in square brackets in using the tikz command as such `\tikz[options...]{...}`. If the tikz code is one line long the curly braces can be omitted saving an additional two bytes.

#### Example:

Both of the following programs output the image at the bottom

```
\documentclass{standalone}\input tikz\begin{document}\tikz{\draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt](0,0)--(0,2)--(1,3.25)--(2,2)--(2,0)--(0,2)--(2,2)--(0,0)--(2,0);\draw(-1.5,0)--(0,1.5);}\end{document}

\documentclass{standalone}\input tikz\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt](0,0)--(0,2)--(1,3.25)--(2,2)--(2,0)--(0,2)--(2,2)--(0,0)--(2,0);\draw(-1.5,0)--(0,1.5);\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

*Credit to WheatWizard for figuring the multiline use of `\tikz`*

Answer (score 4):

## Use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`

By chance I found the following in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf) of the `standalone` package:

> For pictures drawn with TikZ a dedicated `tikz` option is provided which
>   loads the `tikz` package and also configures the `tikzpicture` environment
>   to create a single cropped page.

Thus, instead of

```
\documentclass{standalone}\input tikz\begin{document} ...
```

one can write

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document} ...
```

to save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes refrain from using co-ordinate `(0,0)` completely.
That's an easy one.
Here's a more intricate one:
`(,)` is the same as `(1,1)`.
Found out that one rather by accident.
Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{\draw grid(,);}\end~
```

Output:

[image]